# firebase SDK 9 update current user fail

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using SDK v9 and having issues with updating user profiles fails with

```
TypeError: user._clone is not a function
    at AuthImpl.updateCurrentUser (auth_impl.ts:309)
    at updateUser (firebase.service.ts:41)
    at Object.signUp (firebase.service.ts:31)
    at async handlesubmit (index.tsx:32)
```

here in the firebase SDK

```
async updateCurrentUser(userExtern: User | null): Promise<void> {
    // The public updateCurrentUser method needs to make a copy of the user,
    // and also check that the project matches
    const user = userExtern
      ? (getModularInstance(userExtern) as UserInternal)
      : null;
    if (user) {
      _assert(
        user.auth.config.apiKey === this.config.apiKey,
        this,
        AuthErrorCode.INVALID_AUTH
      );
    }
    return this._updateCurrentUser(user && user._clone(this));
  }
```

Firebase `User` does not have any `_clone` property and if it is supposed be on UserInternal, doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Is this a code snippet fro the Firebase SDK? If so, it might be better to file an issue on the repo for that SDK: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk

Comment: Yes it is Frank. I will do as you suggested. Thanks!